# jQuery how to select iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm trying to select the closest iframe with jQuery. There are a lot of these windows so, I'd like to select the nearest iframe. I'd expect closest() to work, but no luck.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var d = $(document);
   d.on('click', 'a.load_url', function() {
      var myFrame = $(this).closest("iframe").attr("class");
      alert("myFrame: " + myFrame);
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="window2">
   <div class="navbar_top"> 
      <span class="float_left">
         <a href="#" class="load_url">Click Here</a>
      </span>
   </div>
   <div class="window_content" style="border: solid 2px blue; overflow:hidden;">
      <iframe class="classy_iframe" src="http://mx7racing.com"> </iframe>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.closest` traverses up the DOM (parents) and finds the first that matches.

To find the `iFrame` you'll need to do something like this:

```
var myFrame = $(this).closest("div.navbar_top").next('div.window_content').children('iframe').attr("class");
```